# How to use ChangeNotifier with Navigator

Tags: flutter, dart

In my app, I have a model that store the user logged in my app.

```
class AuthenticationModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  User _user;
  User get user => _user;

  void authenticate(LoginData loginData) async {
    // _user = // get user from http call
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void restoreUser() async {
    //_user = // get user from shared prefs
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

The model is registered at the top of the widget tree :

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => AuthenticationModel(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'My App',
        initialRoute: '/',
        routes: {
          '/': (context) => PrehomeScreen(),
          '/home': (context) => HomeScreen()
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Somewhere down the widget tree, I have a button that calls the Model :

```
          child: Consumer<AuthenticationModel>(
            builder: (context, authModel, child) {
              return MyCustomButton(
                text: 'Connect',
                onPressed: () {
                  authModel.authenticate(...)
                },
              );
            },
          ),
```

Now, I would like, somewhere, listen to the changes on the `AuthenticationModel` to trigger a `Navigator.pushReplacmentNamed('/home')` when the user is not null in the model.

I tried to do it in the builder of Prehome :

```
class PrehomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<AuthenticationModel>(
      builder: (context, authModel, child) {
        if (authModel.user != null) {
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed("/home")
        }
        return Container(
          child: // Prehome UI
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

but I have a error when doing it like this :

```
════════ (2) Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
The relevant error-causing widget was:
  Consumer<AuthenticationModel> file:///Users/pierre.degand/Projects/cdc/course_du_coeur/lib/Prehome.dart:13:12
═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

How can I setup such a listener ? Is it a good practice to trigger navigation on model changes like this ?

Thanks

EDIT: I found a way to make this work. Instead of using `Consumer` inside the PrehomeScreen builder, I used the following code :

```
class PrehomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    Provider.of<AuthenticationModel>(context).addListener(() {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed("/home");
    });

    return Container(
      child: // UI
    );
  }
}
```

It works fine, the navigation is executed when the model changes. But there is an error message in the console (printed 3 times) :

```
════════ (4) Exception caught by foundation library ════════════════════════════════════════════════
Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

The app does not crash so, for now, I'm ok with this.
I still want to know if this is a good approach or not.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use Stream or rxdart PublishSubject BehaviourSubject for listening to any activity or to manage global app data.

I implement it using bloc pattern. Basically bloc pattern is just like redux for react means creating a central dataset that contains all app data and you don't have to do prop drilling.

You can create Stream like this.

```
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

class AbcBloc {
  BehaviorSubject<bool> _connectivity;
  AbcBloc() {
    _connectivity = BehaviorSubject<bool>();
  }
  // stream
  Stream<bool> get connectivity => _connectivity.stream;
  // sink
  Function(bool) get updateConnectivity => _connectivity.sink.add;
dispose(){
    _connectivity.close();
}
}

void createAbcBloc() {
  if (abcBloc != null) {
    abcBloc.dispose();
  }
  abcBloc = AbcBloc();
}

AbcBloc abcBloc = AbcBloc();
```

now you can access that abcBloc variable from anywhere and listen to connectivity variable like this

```
import './abcBloc.dart';
void listenConnectivity(){

abcBloc.connectivity.listen((bool connectivety){

here you can perform your operations
});
}
```

and you can update connectivity from abcBloc.updateConnectivity(false);
every time you perform any changes that listener will get called.

remember you have to call listenConnectivity() one time to get it activated;

Answer (score 0):

```
void main() {
  Provider.debugCheckInvalidValueType = null;

  return runApp(
    Provider(
      create: (_) => AuthenticationModel(),
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

    Provider.of<AuthenticationModel>(context).addListener(() {
      final authModel = Provider.of<AuthenticationModel>(context);

      if (authModel.user != null) {
        navigatorKey.currentState.pushReplacementNamed("/home");
      }
    });

    return MaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
      title: 'My App',
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => PrehomeScreen(),
        '/home': (context) => HomeScreen()
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried as well to wrap the `MaterialApp` with a `Consumer` but it's not working as well.

I found a way to make this work see the edit on my first post.

Comment: I have edited. I think the `PrehomeScreen` is unnecessary widget.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `ChangeNotifier` is needed.

```
void main() async {
  final isLoggedIn = await Future.value(true); // get value from shared prefs or your model

  runApp(MyApp(isLoggedIn));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp(this.isLoggedIn);

  final bool isLoggedIn;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: isLoggedIn ? '/home' : '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => HomeScreen(),
        '/login': (context) => LoginScreen()
      },
    );
  }
}
```

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      child: Text('Logout'),
      onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed("/login"),
    );
  }
}

class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      child: Text('Login'),
      onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed("/"),
    );
  }
}
```